# Comparing elements of sequence and set in TLA+

Tags: tla+

Given a sequence S = <<1,2,3,4>> and a set S' = {1,2,3,4,5,6}. How do we check if both of them contain the same values in TLA+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `Range(f) == {f[x]: x \in DOMAIN f}`. Since all sequences are functions, `Range(S)` will give us the values of sequence S. Then we check both have the same elements with `Range(S) = S_prime`.

(We can't call it `S'` because that means "The next state value of `S`".)